# How to write RFID tags using zebra printer

Tags: c#, wpf, rfid

I'm developing WPF Kiosk application. My client request to use RFID tags for an Inventory system. As per requirement first we should print RFID tags, then stick into products before moving them into store. We're using IMPINJ reader for product consume which is working fine for reading/writing RFID tags.

How can we write RFID tags that uses the RFID printer(Printer Model: ZT410)? If I can write tags through printer, will I be able to read through IMPINJ reader?

Comment: you can use the ZPL language in order to encode tags and print any label. and yes once you write a tag you can read it with any reader with certain protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently programming RFID tags from a WPF application, using a Zebra ZD500R RFID printer.

Thoses programmed tags are then read by some other RFID readers (Impinj and Caen devices).

To write your RFID tags, you will have to control the Zebra printer by sending it ZPL commands. Have a look on the Zebra Programming Guides, you will have there description of all the commands you need.

The tags updated by the Zebra will be readable by any other RFID reader.

Comment: Can you please post code snippet? and also, let me know which tag property should I written my information?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Impinj reader capturing all information whatever writing using RFID Printer

Sample code snippet:

^XA
^FO5,5
^A0N,10
^FDwrite example
^FS
^RFW,A
^FD100000000000
^FS
^XZ